# Can´t create Facebook test user account on iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing

i just want to create my first Facebook test user using the Facebook iOS SDK
Unfortunately i get an "Error code 10000". Request didFail.

I simple created a button with the content below.
I´ve also looked at the Facebook documentation but that didn't helped me.
My token is valid and is shown within the NSLog line.. 
What´s wrong with that?
Any help?
Thank you for your time..

```
-(void) createTestAccount:(UIButton*) button{    
    NSLog(@"self.facebook.accessToken : %@", self.facebook.accessToken);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.facebook.accessToken, @"access_token",
                                   nil];

    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/accounts/test-users" , kAppId];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:urlString andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:(id)self];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to create a test account using a mobile app, but it would be far easier to create a test account by going to http://developers.facebook.com and going to the `Roles` section in your App Settings.

However, from your code, it could be that you are using your personal `access_token` to create a test user. You need to use an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/) to create a test user.

Comment: Oh, i didn´t know that. Found nothing about that within the documentation. Thank you very much!!!